# Why we should import #include <string> for string data type and not for the rest?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I noticed when working with strings you should include:

```
#include <string>
```

My question is why this is necessary and not for primitives types like `int` `float` etc?

Thanks

Comment: Long C++ history. The short answer is that `int` and `float` are primitive types supported by the language while `std::string` is a class defined in the standard library header `<string>`.

Comment: Because `std::string` is not primitive type

Comment: Somewhere on your system there will be a file called `string` and you can look inside it and see how `::std::string` works in terms of pointers and ints and other primitive data types. Though that file will probably `#include` others that' you'll have to look through, but the principle is there.

Comment: Some answers over here are useful : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151619/why-are-there-so-many-string-classes-in-the-face-of-stdstring

Comment: *Because* they're primitives. That means they're built into the language. `string` isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you are coming from Python or Javascript background where String is a primitive data type.

It is not so in C++ where the primitive types (called fundamental types in C++) do not have String among them. But `int`, `float` come under the fundamental types.

In C++, `string` is a class type which falls under the compound types (as opposed to fundamental types) category.

For an overview of C++ type system, you can read this [reference on types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type).

Comment: @JuanPOrtiz: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Indeed I'm coming from Javascript although I don't remember import the module in Java neither. Thanks! @P.W

Answer (score 2):

Types like `int`, and `float` are primitive types embedded directly into the C++ language itself. They are very simple, supporting the basic operations that are usually done directly by the processor with a single instruction. While the `std::string` interface might make it seem like it is just as simple, the implementation is actually a whole lot more complicated.

For example, an `int` can just be 4 bytes in memory storing the binary representation of a number. Meanwhile, an `std::string` has to keep track of its length, its capacity, and in many cases have extra memory available to allow for expansion. Adding two `int`s can be done with a single processor instruction while appending to an `std::string` potentially involves allocating a new block of memory in order to store the longer string, copying over the contents, and then freeing the original block of memory.

Because string operations are more complex compared to operations with primitive types like `int` and `float`, `std::string` is provided as a C++ standard library container like `std::vector` instead of a primitive type which is why it has its own header file.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, anything that requires a library typically has a `#include` file that must be used in order to import (though, the way this works should definitely not be confused with the Python `import` statement, the general idea is similar) the declarations of the various entities in the library. This is necessary because C and C++ are 'statically typed' languages, and so the declaration stating what the type is of the thing you're using must be available before you use it. If it weren't, there is no way the compiler could check that the types you were using were correct.

C (and by extension C++) can be thought of as 'portable assembly language' in a certain sense. This means that anything considered a language primitive in C and C++ is almost always something that's supported as a primitive by most CPUs. This means a value a CPU register can hold and manipulate in the appropriate manner with a single instruction.

This has not always been the case on every CPU. For example, there are implementations of C and C++ on systems who's CPUs cannot hold a 32-bit integer. But even on those systems `long` at least is still typically a 32-bit integer and the C compiler will emit several instructions to add two 32-bit values together in multiple steps. And in the early days of C and C++, floating point numbers were typically implemented as a very low-level library because CPUs did not support them directly.

To tell you just how important this is, up until recently C++ had a `register` keyword that was meant as a hint to the compiler that a given variable's value should be held in a CPU register.

A `string` is an arbitrarily long sequence of characters. There are few (if any) CPUs in the world that could represent this directly. So it is not a primitive type, and is instead a type that is implemented by a library of C++ code.

If you are coming from Python... In Python, there are no language constructs that even have the possibility of being implemented directly by storing things in individual CPU registers or performing operations with single CPU instructions. And so the notion of what is a primitive thing supported directly by the language is much broader. And the distinction between something in a library and what is a primitive language construct is also much less distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question: "why this is necessary" we can refer to creator of C++ - Bjarne Stroustrup and his book "The С++ Programming Language":

> **1.3 The Design of C++**
>   C++ has no built-in high-level data types and no high-level primitive operations. For example,
>   the C++ language does not provide a matrix type with an inversion operator or a string type with a
>   concatenation operator. If a user wants such a type, it can be defined in the language itself. In fact,
>   defining a new general-purpose or application-specific type is the most fundamental programming activity in C++. A well-designed user-defined type differs from a built-in type only in the way it is defined, not in the way it is used.

C++ follows principle of modularity and: “not pay for what you don't use”. If user needs another implementation of some feature form standard library - he can include the best available 3rd party library.